# wordpress meta query key serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

So im having some problems getting this query working, im using a meta query to get values that have been stored as a serialized array. Im using the "LIKE" operator like so:

```
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'product',
's'      => $keyword, 
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'raw_data',
        'value' => '"'.$collection.'"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),

), 
 $taxQuery => array(
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( $brandOne, $brandTwo, $brandThree )
    )),
'posts_per_page' => '24', 
'paged' => $paged, 
'post_status'=>'publish' ,
    'order'=>'ASC',
));
}
```

But What I need is target a specific key instead of getting the entire table of "raw_data" I need to get something like `$raw_data["COLLECT"]` and then query the value. 
Anything you guys can think of would be great!

Answer (score -2):

your question about how one can query on serialized data has already been discussed in this post, you may find answer there :  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.